# How to query a custom post type taxonomy to create a taxonomy list for a template page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to build the archive-custom.php page to display a tabbed list. Each custom post type is a "message" tied to a taxonomy that groups and organizes them in a "series". The taxonomy contains the information about each series, including the "series-type" it is and a graphic for each series.

The goal is that the page displays a list of all the "series" of the type "main" with a graphic and taxonomy name. Clicking on a "series" will take you to that "series" page with a list of all "messages"

I have gotten a query to return most of the information that I want, at this point it just returning duplicates, because my query is wrong. It returning the "series" for each "message" so if there are 4 "messages" I'm getting that "series" 4 times. I know the query needs to change.

I also was having an issue returning the name of the taxonomy. In the code below I have it returning 2 different ways - one works but returns the taxonomy name inside a link, which is unnecessary. The other just returns "array" because my syntax is wrong, and I couldn't find an example in the Wordpress codex.

I'm not very familiar with Wordpress queries, but I feel like I have a duplicate query in here that is unnecessary.

```php
<?php       
   //this initial query is returning the results for each message instead of returning just each series in the type "main"  
   $args = array(
      'post_type'   => 'messages',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      //thanks to dmarco for pointing out this should use the meta_query instead
      //not certain how to meta_query the attached taxonomy
      'tax_query'   => array(
         array(
        'taxonomy' => 'cpt_series',
        'field'    => 'series_type',
        'terms'    => 'main'
         )
      )
   );


   $series = new WP_Query( $args );
   if( $series->have_posts() ) :
?>
      <ul>
<?php
      while( $series->have_posts() ) :
         $series->the_post();

         //get the custom taxonomy fields and assign them to var
         //this query is to access the custom post type fields.
         $types = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cpt_series',
            'hide_empty' => true,
         ));

         foreach($types as $type) {
            $image = get_field('series_graphic', 'cpt_series_' . $type->term_id . '' );
            $seriesLink = get_term_link($type->term_id, $taxonomy = 'cpt_series');
            //This title doesn't work - syntax is wrong
            $seriesTitle = wp_get_post_terms('name');

            if ( has_term( $type->term_id, 'cpt_series')) {
               $seriesGraphic = $image['url'];
            }
         }
?>

         <li>
            <a href="<?=$seriesLink?>">
<?php 
               echo '<img src="' . $seriesGraphic . '" />';
               echo $seriesTitle;
               $seriesTitle = the_terms($post->ID, 'sermon_series', '');
?>
            </a>
         </li>
<?php
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
?>
      </ul>
<?php
   else :
      esc_html_e( 'No series available!', 'text-domain' );
   endif;           
?>
```

It's very close to doing what I want, again just getting the "series"
 for each "message" instead of just a list of all the "series" in the type "main". Would love to know how to properly get the 'name' returned as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered how to do this by querying the taxonomy directly instead.

```php
$terms = get_terms(array(
   'taxonomy' => 'cpt_series',
   'hide_empty' => true,
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
         'key'     => 'series_type',
         'value'   => 'main',
         'compare' => 'LIKE'
      ),
   ),
));

if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
   echo '<ul>';
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $image = get_field('series_graphic', 'cpt_series_' . $term->term_id . '' );
      $seriesLink = get_term_link($term->term_id, $taxonomy = 'cpt_series');
      $seriesGraphic = $image['url'];
   ?>
      <li>
         <a href="<?=$seriesLink?>">
            <img src="<?=$seriesGraphic?>" />
            <?=$term->name?>
         </a>
      </li>                     
 <?php                  
   }
   echo '</ul>';
} else {
   echo 'No term found.';
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem you have:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'messages',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query'   => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cpt_series',
            'field'    => 'series_type',
            'terms'    => 'main'
        )
    )
);
```

`'field' => 'series_type'` - you name here by what you search and options are:  `term_id`, `name`, `slug` or `term_taxonomy_id`. Go to database and find table wp_terms. There you may see those values. So I assume these lines should look something like:

```
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'cpt_series',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => 'main'
)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to search by the slug, but to limit the results by the series_type.

series_type is a custom drop down field, and series_type is the id of the field.
one of the options in the drop down is 'main'. The current search does return results, just not limited to the the 'main' results.

Comment: And that's additional field you added to taxonomy cpt_series? Then you must use meta_query for that.

Comment: Just found the query should use the meta_query to query the custom field - not certain how to query that in the attached taxonomy instead of in the post.

Comment: I don't understand your structure exactly. If you can explain in details I might try to write that query. Meanwhile, you may do a little research in [Codex WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: thanks man, I posted the solution to the search, the only thing I have left to do is to sort it by a custom date field. I found how, its not as important right now with the data that I have so I'll work on it later.
in case your interested here is how:
https://hirejordansmith.com/order-get_terms-based-custom-field/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this meta query for your initial query.

```
$args = array(
     'post_type'   => 'messages',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'meta_query' => array(
        array(
         'key' => 'series_type',
         'value' => 'main',
         'compare' => 'IN',

            )

     ) 
 );
```

Comment: That returns blank. My guess is this is because it is querying the post for the field, and the field doesn't exist on the post - it is in the taxonomy.